# How can you generate a report like SYBUNT - but for consistent donors?

Tags: reports, custom-reports

Is there a way to generate a report that demonstrates donors that have consistently donated over the course of the past 3 years - including this year? The SYBUNT report is great for looking up potential donors that have given in the past - but we want to find donors that have given consistently - in an effort to get them to donate more or help increase donations from others.

Seems like I can possibly modify the SYBUNT report to give a version of that - but not quite.

Comment: Have you tried poking around any of these reports https://civicrm.org/extensions/advanced-fundraising-reports

Comment: Also worth exploring Summary Fields if you don't know of it. Then you could potentially add a Summary Field for 'last year', previous year, previous 2nd year. Then you could Smart Group those for whom none of those fields are Null